# Implementing sum of integers up to N in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am trying to Design hardware that will produce the following sequence, F = sum of the first N whole number, that is, 1+2...+N.
(e.g. If N=3, F=1+2+3=6). I am implementing a module that whenever its input N changes, it produces F, at latest N clock cycles later. N will be any 4-bit number (meaning that F has to be 7 bits long). N will not change while new a new F is being calculated. Here is my attempt:

```
module Fib (clock, reset, N, Fib);

input clock, reset;  input [3:0] N;  
output [6:0] Fib;

reg [6:0] Fib;  
// local vars  
reg [2:0] Nprev; 
reg [2:0] count;  
reg  state, next_state;

// control lines
reg [1:0] Fmux, Cmux;

//status line
wire zero, equal;

parameter wait4newN=1'b0,  
  wait4Zero=1'b1; 

// Datapath
always@(posedge clock)
  case(Fmux)
    2'h0 : Fib <= N;
    2'h1 : Fib <= Fib + count;
  endcase

always@(posedge clock)
 case (Cmux)
    2'h0 : count <= N-1;
    2'h1 : count <= count - 1;
  endcase

assign zero = (count == 0);
assign equal = (Nprev==N);

// Controller
always@(posedge clock)
  Nprev <= N;

always@(posedge clock)
  if (reset) state <= wait4newN;
    else 
      state <= next_state;

always@(*)
  begin
    Fmux = 0; Cmux = 0;
    case (state) // synopsys full_case parallel_case
      wait4newN : 
           if (!equal) 
             begin 
               Fmux = 0; Cmux = 0;
               next_state=wait4newN;
             end
           else 
              begin 
                Fmux = 1; Cmux = 1;
                next_state=wait4Zero;
              end
      wait4Zero : 
          if(!zero)
              begin
                  Fmux = 1; Cmux = 1;
                  next_state = wait4Zero;
              end
          else
            begin
                Fmux = 0; Cmux =0;
                next_state =wait4newN;
            end
      default:
         $display("why am I here?");
      endcase
  end
 endmodule
```

My test fixture is

```
// Testbench
module test;

reg  clk, reset;
reg [3:0] N;
reg [6:0] Fib; 

  // Instantiate device under test
Fib fibInstance(.clock(clk),.reset(reset), .N(N), .Fib(Fib));

  initial begin
    // Dump waves
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars(1, test);

    clk = 0;
    reset = 1;
    N = 5;
    $display("wait4newN N: %0h, Fib: %0h",
      N, Fib);

    toggle_clk;
    $display("wait4Zero N: %0h, Fib: %0h",
      N, Fib);

    toggle_clk;
    $display("wait4Zero N: %0h, Fib: %0h",
      N, Fib);

    toggle_clk;
    $display("wait4Zero N: %0h, Fib: %0h",
      N, Fib);

    toggle_clk;
    $display("wait4Zero N: %0h, Fib: %0h",
      N, Fib);

    toggle_clk;
    $display("wait4Zero N: %0h, Fib: %0h",
      N, Fib);

    toggle_clk;
    $display("wait4newN N: %0h, Fib: %0h",
      N, Fib);
  end

  task toggle_clk;
    begin
      #5 clk = ~clk;
      #5 clk = ~clk;
    end
  endtask

endmodule
```

The result of simulation is XX for F.

```
[2017-10-21 20:17:23 EDT] iverilog '-Wall' '-g2012' design.sv testbench.sv  && unbuffer vvp a.out  
VCD info: dumpfile dump.vcd opened for output.
wait4newN N: 5, Fib: xx
wait4Zero N: 5, Fib: xx
wait4Zero N: 5, Fib: xx
wait4Zero N: 5, Fib: xx
wait4Zero N: 5, Fib: xx
wait4Zero N: 5, Fib: xx
wait4newN N: 5, Fib: xx
Done
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Thank you very much for you time in advance.

Comment: one thing is that you forgot to clean the `reset` signal in your test bench, so it causes toggling between *wat4newN* and *wait4Zero* back and forth. Also it looks like you have a race between *Fmux* and *clock* due to the reset signal behavior, making it '0' at posedge.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems due to **reset**. Here is a plain explanation for what is happening:

In your **Fib module**, you **are not initializing variables on *reset***. When reset is applied, the state goes from '**X**' to '**wait4newN**'. Now **the combinational block gets triggered on same clock and the case statement is executed**. Thereby **FMux** goes from **X->1 directly**. As a result the equation "**Fib <= Fib + count**" always yields '**X**' since **Fib** was **never initialized to zero**.

Apart from this, you are **never deasserting reset** to zero from your testbench. So the FSM state never changes.

In the **Fib** module, use the reset in sequential blocks.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin // Assuming synchronous reset
  if(reset) begin
    // Reset variables
  end else begin
    // other logic
  end
end
```

More information about handling resets is available at [this site](http://www.asic-world.com/tidbits/all_reset.html) and [Cummings Reset related Paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2003Boston_Resets.pdf).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much for the clarification and also the links!